# Configure the FROM of send email on Case

Tags: email, workflow, business-logic

[image]

Is it possible to configure the emails that appears on the "FROM" based on the profile or role or some type of criteria of the current user? If it is, how can I do it? 
 thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is via Apex.  The [QuickActionDefaultsHandler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_QuickAction_QuickActionDefaultsHandler.htm) class allows you to prepopulate any of the values in the email UI based on whatever logic you like.